# how to use django-emoticons in django 3

Tags: django

i've found on Django-PyPI django-emoticons package i've installed it and did all the things in the settings file i even have {% load static %} in my template and i still have an error like: "django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library."
in my {% extends "blog/base.html" %} base template i also have {% load static %}. Are there any other credentials for Django 3 to use this package?

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
'users.apps.UsersConfig',
'crispy_forms',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'emoticons',
```

]

**template**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load emoticons_tags %}
{% block content %}
   <div class="content-section">
       <form method="POST">
           {% csrf_token %}
           <fieldset class="form-group">
               <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Blog Post</legend>
               {% emoticons %}
               {{ form|crispy }}
               {% endemoticons %}
           </fieldset>
           <div class="form-group">
               <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
           </div>
       </form>
   </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Can you show the fill error trace

Comment: @ger.s.brett i've put it in to another answer it was too long for comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 1021, in find_library
    return parser.libraries[name]
KeyError: 'staticfiles'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 76, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\emoticons\templatetags\emoticons_tags.py", line 8, in <module>
    from emoticons.settings import EMOTICONS_LIST
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\emoticons\settings.py", line 151, in <module>
    EMOTICON_TEMPLATE = get_template('emoticons/emoticon.html')
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 15, in get_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 29, in get_template
    return Template(
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 194, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 477, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 475, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 1078, in load
    lib = find_library(parser, name)
  File "C:\Users\wtaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 1023, in find_library
    raise TemplateSyntaxError(
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
crispy_forms_field
crispy_forms_filters
crispy_forms_tags
crispy_forms_utils
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version of emoticon you use is not compatible with django 3. You could just change this by looking into the emoticon directory and replace in all html templates the line:

```
{% load staticfiles %}<img class="emoticon emoticon-{{ code }}" src="{% static image %}" alt="{{ name }}" />
```

with

```
{% load static %}<img class="emoticon emoticon-{{ code }}" src="{% static image %}" alt="{{ name }}" />
```